# Are C# WebSocket occasional disconnects typical and expected?

Tags: c#, websocket, coinbase-api

I am using C# WebSocket code to connect to the Coinbase API. The Websocket will occasionally disconnect, sometimes after 45 minutes or so, sometimes after many hours. Is this type of disconnection something that is simply just to be expected over the internet? In other words, should I just code reconnection logic to handle this as a typical/normal case? Or should the WebSocket hardly ever disconnect, and theoretically  stay connected for many days?

Comment: Ideally the connection should stay open forever.  45 minutes is very short.  How much data is being transfered (Rate and size)?  A WebSocket uses TCP as transport layer.  You can use a sniffer and look for the TCP connect closing indicated by [FIN].

Comment: I tried using SignalR and standard .NET websockets. They both will disconnect after a while. The data rate is pretty low, probably 10kb/s or so. Will wireshark work for sniffing?

Comment: Yes.  It will give more info on the closure.  Either the connection is being closed or you are getting CRC errors in the channel.  So you will see repeats.   TCP for each message gets an ACK.  If ACK is not seen the message is repeated.  After 3 repeats the connection will close.

Comment: Network connection reliability has nothing to do with programming. It depends entirely on the specifics of the network you're using. Some networks maintain connections for years, while others can't keep a connection more than a few seconds at a time. Most networks fall somewhere in a comfortable medium range.

Comment: Thanks @PeterDuniho - To rephrase my question, if my websocket program running on my laptop is disconnecting from my standard household wifi a couple times a day, do I chalk this up as somewhat common and expected? Or do I open up the wireshark and dig in?

Comment: That really depends on the specifics of your "standard household wifi" (something that doesn't actually exist...we all have unique network situations). You should post your question to https://superuser.com/, or possibly https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/. It's not a programming question. As far as your program goes: you shouldn't care whether disconnects are "normal" or not; the code **must** be able to handle them gracefully.